# Intellisense for html does not work if file association set to django-html

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using vscode for my django project and for templates to get help with Django Template Language, I installed the [Django extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django).

Now after installing this extension the intelliSense for html tags is not working anymore. So, now I have to write whole html tags and its getting troublesome.

Anyway to enable html intelliSense for django-html type files too?

my project settings.json file code

```
{
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "files.associations": {
        "**/*.html": "html",
        "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
        "**/templates/*": "django-html",
        "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
        "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "django-html": "html"
    },
    "beautify.language": {
        "html": [
            "htm",
            "html",
            "django-html"
        ]
    },
}
```

If I change 'django-html' to 'html' in above code then the html intellisense works but then the help for DTL does not work anymore.

I have set the 'django-html' to 'html' for emmet but still it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't directly auto complete html tags in django-html file but putting

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "django-html": "html"
    },
```

before file association has made possible to use emmet abbreviations default for html. This works too for me.

Like now typing "li" and selecting from suggestions puts the complete tags there by automatically