# Vscode configure path intellisense with django templates

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, django-templates, intellisense

Is it possible to configure path intellisense to work with Django template? I just installed the extension and it works perfectly if you only use html but when you use django-html it doesn't work :(

This works:

```
<img class="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle" alt="User Image" src="../static/img/patients/patient1.jpg">
```

This doesn't work:

```
<img class="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle" alt="User Image" src="{% static 'img/Patients/patient1.jpg' %}">
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67561720/intellisense-for-html-does-not-work-if-file-association-set-to-django-html) and I thought it was a configuration problem, but I see that it is not, since it works perfectly when I do not use the syntax for Django static files

https://github.com/ChristianKohler/PathIntellisense